# How do I change the default text in dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am using [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to upload files. However, I'm having difficulty changing the default text.

I've tried instantiating the dropzone class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".foo").dropzone({ dictDefaultMessage: "hello" });
});
```

With this markup:

```
    <div class="span4">
      <form action="http://localhost/post" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="drop3" class="foo" enctype="multipart/form-data"> </form>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
      <form action="http://localhost/post" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="drop4" class="foo" enctype="multipart/form-data"> </form>
  </div>
```

This certainly gives me the ability to upload files but the default text is blank.

I tested the following:

```
 $(".foo").dropzone();
```

and I appear to get the same result - no default text. So.. how do I change the default text?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Add an element within your dropzone form as follows:

```
<div class="dz-message" data-dz-message><span>Your Custom Message</span></div>
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works, while changing "dictDefaultMessage" as a setting seems to do nothing. This is mostly because the text is replaced with an image that has text on it.

Comment: This work, but what do for all other kind of messages? There is a huge hole in the documentation

Comment: this is work, BUT, this is forced me to click only the text to show the fileupload dialog. the clicking outside the text is now showing the fileupload

Comment: I'm using the <dropzone> html tag and have no other option as I am in an angular project. placing the above within that is not working.

Answer (score 103):

You can change all **default messages** with this:

```
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictDefaultMessage = "Drop files here to upload";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictFallbackMessage = "Your browser does not support drag'n'drop file uploads.";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictFallbackText = "Please use the fallback form below to upload your files like in the olden days.";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictFileTooBig = "File is too big ({{filesize}}MiB). Max filesize: {{maxFilesize}}MiB.";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictInvalidFileType = "You can't upload files of this type.";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictResponseError = "Server responded with {{statusCode}} code.";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictCancelUpload = "Cancel upload";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictCancelUploadConfirmation = "Are you sure you want to cancel this upload?";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictRemoveFile = "Remove file";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictMaxFilesExceeded = "You can not upload any more files.";
```

Comment: See list of all message keys here: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-dictDefaultMessage

Comment: Now, you need to use this - Dropzone.options.dictDefaultMessage = "Drop files here to upload";

Answer (score 45):

When creating the dropzone you can set the default message like this.

```
var dropzone = new Dropzone("form.dropzone", {
   dictDefaultMessage: "Put your custom message here"
});
```

Then

```
$('div.dz-default.dz-message > span').show(); // Show message span
$('div.dz-default.dz-message').css({'opacity':1, 'background-image': 'none'});
```

Answer (score 12):

First add an id to your form, say `mydz`, then add this js:

```
Dropzone.options.mydz = {
    dictDefaultMessage: "your custom message"
};
```

The whole page (index.php in this case):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="dropzone.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./dropzone.css">
<title></title>

</head>

<body>

<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="mydz"></form>
<script type="text/javascript">

Dropzone.options.mydz = {
    dictDefaultMessage: "Put your custom message here"
};


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what documentation says, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me

Comment: Did you add an id to your form? If you did, it can't not work. Add the dropzone.js to the top of your page and the JS I gave you at the bottom of the page, and it must work.

Comment: I just updated my post with the whole page, copy paste that, include the relevant files, and see if it works.

Answer (score 10):

this text is in dropzone's default config, You can overwrite like this:

```
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictDefaultMessage = "Your text";
```

Comment: Thank you! I really didn't need to change the message but this is the only thing that helped me change the defaultOptions ☺

Answer (score 8):

```
myDropzonePhotos = new Dropzone('#dropzone-test',
{
    url                : 'upload_usuario.php?id_usuario=' + id_usuario,
    maxFiles           : 1, 
    thumbnailWidth     : 1200,
    thumbnailHeight    : 300,
    dictDefaultMessage : 'Change the text here!',
    init: function()
    {
     ....
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! When answering questions, instead of just providing code, please also explain it. Read the guide to answering questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 6):

I fiddled with this for hours.

For some reason, these 3 things needed to be done:

1. My dropzone  tags could not be on the same page I was using dropzone on. I had to reference them on the template page
2. The element you are turning into a dropzone has to have a class of 'dropzone'
3. You have to add the following to the top of the js file for the page i was working on.

`Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;`

To Initialize:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#id-upload-dropzone", {
    url: "/home/Upload",
    dictDefaultMessage: 'Drop image here (or click) to capture/upload'
});
```

Once I had all 3 in order, the dictDefaultMessage option worked.

Answer (score 4):

For localizing Dropzone in Asp.Net Razor Pages I use the below method to avoid decoded chars :

**Create HTML element for all messages**

```html
<!-- localization elements -->

<div class="modal" aria-hidden="true">

    <span id="dictDefaultMessage">@_localizer["Drop files here or click to upload."]</span>

    <span id="dictFallbackMessage">@_localizer["Your browser does not support drag'n'drop file uploads."]</span>

    <span id="dictFallbackText">@_localizer["Please use the fallback form below to upload your files like in the olden days."]</span>

    <span id="dictFileTooBig">@_localizer["File is too big ({{filesize}}MiB). Max filesize: {{maxFilesize}}MiB."]</span>

    <span id="dictInvalidFileType">@_localizer["You can't upload files of this type."]</span>

    <span id="dictResponseError">@_localizer["Server responded with {{statusCode}} code."]</span>

    <span id="dictCancelUpload">@_localizer["Cancel upload"]</span>

    <span id="dictCancelUploadConfirmation">@_localizer["Are you sure you want to cancel this upload?"]</span>

    <span id="dictUploadCanceled">@_localizer["Upload canceled."]</span>

    <span id="dictRemoveFile">@_localizer["Delete"]</span>

    <span id="dictRemoveFileConfirmation">@_localizer["Are you sure you want to delete this file?"]</span>

    <span id="dictMaxFilesExceeded">@_localizer["You can not upload any more files."]</span>

    <span id="dictFileSizeUnits_TB">@_localizer["TB"]</span>

    <span id="dictFileSizeUnits_GB">@_localizer["GB"]</span>

    <span id="dictFileSizeUnits_MB">@_localizer["MB"]</span>

    <span id="dictFileSizeUnits_KB">@_localizer["KB"]</span>

    <span id="dictFileSizeUnits_b">@_localizer["b"]</span>

</div>
```

Then bind messages to Dropzone element:

```js
<script>
// get elements for localization

        with (Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions) {

            dictDefaultMessage = document.getElementById("dictDefaultMessage").innerText;

            dictFallbackMessage = document.getElementById("dictFallbackMessage").innerText;

            dictFallbackText = document.getElementById("dictFallbackText").innerText;

            dictFileTooBig = document.getElementById("dictFileTooBig").innerText;

            dictInvalidFileType = document.getElementById("dictInvalidFileType").innerText;

            dictResponseError = document.getElementById("dictResponseError").innerText;

            dictCancelUpload = document.getElementById("dictCancelUpload").innerText;

            dictCancelUploadConfirmation = document.getElementById("dictCancelUploadConfirmation").innerText;

            dictUploadCanceled = document.getElementById("dictUploadCanceled").innerText;

            dictRemoveFile = document.getElementById("dictRemoveFile").innerText;

            dictRemoveFileConfirmation = document.getElementById("dictRemoveFileConfirmation").innerText; // if this is null, the user will not be prompted when deleting file.

            dictMaxFilesExceeded = document.getElementById("dictMaxFilesExceeded").innerText;

            dictFileSizeUnits = {

                tb: document.getElementById("dictFileSizeUnits_TB").innerText,

                gb: document.getElementById("dictFileSizeUnits_GB").innerText,

                mb: document.getElementById("dictFileSizeUnits_MB").innerText,

                kb: document.getElementById("dictFileSizeUnits_KB").innerText,

                b: document.getElementById("dictFileSizeUnits_b").innerText

            };

        };

</script>
```

for a complete drag-drop file upload sample using Dropzone see this GitHub repository : https://github.com/LazZiya/FileUpload

Answer (score 3):

in the css of dropzone look for

```
.dropzone .dz-default.dz-message
```

in this class delete

```
background-image: url("../images/spritemap.png");
```

the next thing to do is search this class

```
.dropzone .dz-default.dz-message span {
  display: none;
}
```

and change it to display:block

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't adverse to JQuery, this will hide the default image:

```
$('form.dropzone').find('div.default.message').css('background-image','none');
```

and, this will show the default span which you can change to be whatever you want:

```
$('form.dropzone').find('div.default.message').find('span').show();
$('form.dropzone').find('div.default.message').find('span').empty();
$('form.dropzone').find('div.default.message').find('span').append('Drop files here or click here to upload an image.');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating Dropzones Programmatically then you have to set your options like below:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

profilePicture = new Dropzone('#profile-picture', {
    url: "/uploadPicture.php",

    // if you are using laravel ..., you dont need to put csrf in meta tag
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    },

    dictDefaultMessage: "Your default message Will work 100%",

    /other options
    paramName: "profile_picture",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFilesize: 1,
    maxFiles: 10,

    dictRemoveFile: "Remove",

});
```

If you are using it like this, It wont work ...

```
let myDropzone = new Dropzone("#profile-picture", {

    url: "/uploadPicture.php",
    // if you are using laravel ..., you dont need to put csrf in meta tag
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    },

});

myDropzone.options.profilePicture = {

    dictDefaultMessage: "This message not gonna work",

    paramName: "profile_picture",
};
```